# Team club with CPTs and user registration + user dashboard

Tags: custom-post-types, user-registration, dashboard, membership, members

I am creating a site to manage a rugby club, which has the following structure:

Disciplines> Categories> Divisions> Teams> Players

I was able to create the structure using JetEngine, CPTs and relationships between the CPTs.

What I need now is to find a plugin for player registration, which allows me to:

- Request personal information from the user.
- Request the type of partner (as "player" or as "partner").
- If the user chooses as "player": he must choose a discipline> category> division> team and other data.
- The user must have a "user panel" where they can see their information, fees paid, fees to pay, etc. (This is very important)

I've been looking at various membership plugins: memberpress, paid membership pro, restrict content pro, etc. but I BELIEVE that none of them have what I need or I'm not seeing it.

Comment: You're going to have a VERY hard time finding something that works; and when you do, you'll find that all sorts of assumptions have been made with regards to how things SHOULD work and then you'll need to decide if you want to change how your rugby club operates or see if you can find someone to change these things for you.  (I speak from personal experience here with regards to football clubs and their websites... ...I'm currently building a custom club management tool for a football club and it's A LOT of work.)  :-(

Comment: What I did was build an invitation system & customized User Registration form to replace the standard WordPress registration set-up.  So if you register just by 'registering' then you fill in all your pertinent information - but if you receive an invite from a team, then some of your information is auto-completed & hidden & there are also a series of validations (11) that check whether or not you're eligible to join that team.  The benefit is that if someone has registered once, they can just be 'invited' to other teams, but don't have to fill out all of the information over & over again.

Comment: Failing that - look at using TeamSnap for your club; they have a WordPress multi-site installation and proprietary plugins that integrate some parts of their platform with WordPress.  (They won't release the plugin to the public, I've asked.)  https://www.teamsnap.com